# neo4j : Traverser only get first and last node

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

I assume I have an error in my code, but I can't find which one
I have three nodes :
a, b and c
there are linked so 
(a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r2]-(c) (I'm 100% sure of this, I checked with neo4j Community)

But my Program can only find the first and the last one. The second one, b, is always ignored.
Here is my method :

```
static List<Node> getNodes(Node startNode,final Node endNode,boolean uniqueResult,List<RelationshipType> relationshipTypes)
{
    List<Node> result=new ArrayList<>();
    try(Transaction tx=getInstance()._graph.beginTx())
    {
        TraversalDescription td = getInstance()._graph.traversalDescription().breadthFirst();
        for(RelationshipType relationshipType:relationshipTypes)
            td=td.relationships(relationshipType);
        td=td.evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition());
        if(!uniqueResult)
            td=td.uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH);
        td=td.evaluator(new Evaluator() {
            @Override
            public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
                boolean isEndNode=path.endNode().equals(endNode);
                return Evaluation.of(isEndNode, !isEndNode);
            }
        });      
        Traverser tr=td.traverse( startNode );
        for(Path path:tr)   
            result.add(path.endNode());

        tx.success();
    }   
    return result;
}
```

startNode is a
endNode is c
uniqueResult is true (but I tried with false, no change)
relationShipTypes contains r1 and r2.

I have no clue, why it doesn't work
Thanks for your help

Comment: are you looking for path.nodes()

Comment: actually yes! Well, it seems that I still didn't understand the purpose of paths. Thanks. Please put it as answer, so I can validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Path](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html) is a collection of node-relationship-node.

With

- length() you can access the path length, i.e the number of rels
- nodes() returns an Iterable of nodes in the path
- relationship()  returns an Iterable of relationships in the path
- path itself is an Iterable of property containers
- startNode() and endNode() return those respectively
- lastRelationship() returns the last relationship in the path, as it is more frequently used

See also: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_path